# Optical density machine name

Tags: terminology

What is the name of the machine used to measure optical density? We used it in a lab but I can't remember what they called it.

Comment: densitometer? turbidometer? spectrometer? spectrophotometer? There are many such devices and some details on the type of experiment may help here.

Comment: Hmm I think it was the spectrometer. That sounds right. We where measuring the growth of cell cultures.

Comment: I'd bet the farm that it's a spectrophotometer.

Answer (score 6):

Optical Density is synonymous with **absorbance** which is based on the principle of absorption of light. The machine that is used to measure absorbance is called a **spectrophotometer**. Spectrometer does not indicate that light absorbance is being measured. A spectrometer can measure any spectrum; for e.g. Mass Spectrometer measures the spectrum of molecular mass (to be precice mass per charge).

Cell density can be also measured by the level of light scattering; turbidimeters or nephelometers are used for these kind of measurements.

*PS: You should pay more attention in your class* :P

Comment: Also called a spec, for short.

Comment: When you use a spectrophotometer to measure culture density you are actually measuring turbidity/light scattering, not absorbance.